# Wireshark can't see the dropped packets by iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, wireshark

I'm running wireshark(2.6.8) and iptables(v1.8.2 nf_tables) instances on my computer. I saw that others can see the dropped packets with wireshark:

- [How can Wireshark see packets dropped by iptables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248090/how-can-wireshark-see-packets-dropped-by-iptables)
- https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/4521/wireshark-see-packets-which-should-be-dropped-by-iptables

My iptables configuration:

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -F INPUT

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

* whitelisting some IP addresses *

iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
```

I can see the dropped packets in the logs, but I certainly can't see the packets which are dropped by iptables in wireshark on any interface.

I'm not sure, but it could be because of the newer version of the iptables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark can only see incoming packets which get dropped because the dropping occurs later. For outgoing packets the `iptables` drop occurs before the wireshark reading so you do not see such packets in wireshark.

Think of `wireshark` as the outer layer (hardware) and of `iptables` as the inner layer (software).

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, can you please specify in your answer what is the exact reason behind this?

Comment: @user426506 What do you mean by "this"? That is just the Linux structure. But any different structure is hard to imagine. The network interface is literally the interface to the outside world. So it must be the last component a network packet passes through before leaving the system and the first component it passes through. The interface just sends whatever is given to it. In other words: The system must first decide what to send (`iptables`) before actually sending it. You cannot reverse that order.

Comment: I've just realized that if I want to understand it perfectly I need to learn a bit 
about the underlying code in the kernel, which is responsible for these mechanics 
and how iptables and wireshark solve their problems. This surpasses a simple 
request for clarification, so just ignore my comment please.